# Seeking Sqlite no-op command

Tags: sqlite, no-op

Is there a command which I can run to do nothing (or very little) which will never error?

I need something for testing porpoises.

Comment: I'm intrigued — how do you test [porpoises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porpoise)?

Comment: Porpoisfully, of course

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A comment does nothing (but your database driver might complain if there is not command at all):

```
/* Hello, world! */
```

Unknown [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) statements are ignored, and do not return anything:

```
PRAGMA testing_porpoises;
```

If you need a statement that returns an empty result set, you need a SELECT:

```
SELECT 0 WHERE 0;
```

Comment: "PRAGMA testing_porpoises;" it is ;-)  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For example a simple constant select could do:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 0;
```